# what time format is this?

Tags: json, time, format

I have a json file of data and the only item for time i see is this:

`createdAt: 1332775669`

what time format is this? I am not sure how to format this in order to get the actual time?

Comment: ask the person who created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Unix time stamp. You can read it into a JavaScript Date object simply by using `new Date(timeStamp*1000)`.

Comment: You probably want timeStamp*1000 as the constructor wants ms

Answer (score 0):

UNIX or timestamp
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm